# Nvidia Gtx 970: Resolution stuck at 1024x768

Tags: 18.04, display-resolution, nvidia-geforce

I have already read a bunch of threads and haven't gotten anywhere. I installed Ubuntu command-line only, then installed the Gnome desktop environment separately.

Upon booting the desktop, the proper resolution appeared. I went to **Software & Updates >> Additional drivers**, then switched to the recommended "Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nividia-driver-430 (proprietary, tested)". I hit Apply Changes, then rebooted the machine once finished.

The resolution broke. I tried reverting to the original "Using X.Org X Server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)". No dice. The resolution remained at 1024x768.

After reading through the xorg.0.conf log it appears the monitor is not recognized, which is causing the problem.

xrandr output:

```
$ xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+)+) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768 76.00*
```

There is no x11/xorg.conf.d file. Output of X -configure

```
X -configure
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have also booted with nomodeset and followed the instructions in that thread. No dice.

Comment: After reading through the xorg.0.conf log it appears the monitor is not recognized, which is causing the problem.